Django PasswordResetForm Not Sending Emails with Custom Domain
I'm encountering an issue with Django's PasswordResetForm where emails are not being sent when a custom domain is specified. Below is the save method within my custom form:
class PasswordResetForm(auth_forms.PasswordResetForm):
    """
    This form takes the same structure as its parent from :py:mod:`django.contrib.auth`
    """

    def save(self, *args, domain_override=None, request=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Generates a one-use only link for resetting password and sends to the
        user.
        """
        
        site = get_current_site(request)
        if domain_override is not None:
            site.domain = site.name = domain_override
        for user in self.get_users(self.cleaned_data["email"]):
            self.send_password_reset_email(site, user, request)

    def send_password_reset_email(self, site, user, request=None):
        extra_context = {
            "user": user,
            "site": site,
            "reset_url": get_password_reset_url(user),
            "request": request,
        }
        CustomerDispatcher().send_password_reset_email_for_user(user, extra_context)

I tried to retrieve the domain from the request using domain = request.get_host() but still facing the issue.
Additional Context: When the domain_override parameter is provided with a custom domain, emails are not being sent to users. The get_current_site function is being used to fetch the current site based on the request. The custom domain is correctly retrieved and assigned to the site variable, but emails are still not being sent. The send_password_reset_email method is responsible for sending the password reset email to the user with the correct reset link.
Question: How can I ensure that emails are sent successfully with the custom domain specified in domain_override?
